# Django | Sube bien archivo image, muestra ruta imagen en template pero no se ve la imagen

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Un modeli permtie subir la imagen, se sube la imagen sin problema ya que se ve en el directorio, y en el template se muestra el código correctamente, pero no se ve la imagen:

Lo que muestra el template en vez de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen está en el directorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo.settings.local.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

El template parece que muestra bien la ruta de imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** models.py

```
class ImageDevice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)
    image_device = models.ImageField(upload_to='devices/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagen de dispositivos'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Device(models.Model):
    image_device = models.ForeignKey(ImageDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dispositivos'
        ordering = ['installation_device']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

Comment: ¿Y que te muestra la consola del navegador? Por allí puedes ir depurando un poco para saber la causa del problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no solo debes de agregar la configuración de los MEDIA_URL si no que también ir a las urls principales de Django e indicar que considere las urls de los archivos media:

```
#
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Gracias Cristhian. Perfecto.